# Change value of variable insead loop Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm newer on bash scripting ,I have a global variable that I want to change his value insead a loop in my script but still get an error that commande not found

this my script :

```
SCRIPT_BASE = "/home/scripts/test-Scripts"
CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH = ""


declare -a arr=("A" "B"  "C" "D")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   if [ $i == "A" ]; then
       CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH = $SCRIPT_BASE 
       echo -e "Current Path  :  $CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH"
   fi
done
```

when I run this script I get that CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH  commande not found
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `a=b` and `a = b` parse completely differently. Variable assignment must not contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks guys the problem was the spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` you should be really cautious about spaces in `if` conditions but also when you assign a value to a variable.

Replace in your code the following tree lines:

```
SCRIPT_BASE="/home/scripts/test-Scripts"
CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH=""
CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH=$SCRIPT_BASE
```

If you keep a space after the variable name bash will interpret it as a command and as you do not have commands `SCRIPT_BASE`, `CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH`, `CURRENT_SCRIPT_PATH` in your current `$PATH` you have the error `command not found` that is produced.